# Best way of dynamically assigning variables in a C++ interpreter

Tags: c++, native, interpreter

I'm currently working on an interpreter I created that uses a pseudo c++ syntax. I am looking for the best way of storing variables created by the interpreter.

Currently I am using dynamic arrays that store pointers to those variables, but surely there's a better way? Maybe some sort of inline assembler code to control a memory block?

I'm not too concerned about portability as I am willing to rewrite those pieces of code for every major OS. I am simply looking for a way to create a memory block without it being locked to a single type. For my current testing I am using the MingW compiler on Windows.

Any ideas will be greately appreciated.

Comment: What is better for you? Faster? Less memory-consuming? More elegant to implement?

Comment: Are you talking about how to manage the heap, or how to allocate things on the stack (if your language supports that)? What is the problem with the current solution? Performance?

Comment: @BjornPollex: I am not too concerned about readibility as i comment my code very well. I want it to be as effecient as possible in terms of being faster. memory usage im not so concerned about

Comment: @Dervall: my code actually works fine. Problem is that i am (maybe a bit too much) obsessed with effeciency in terms of speed. If you know of any good resources for reading up on managing the heap or stack let me know. Honestly, I'm still a bit inexperienced in that regard

Comment: @user1166877: If you are truly concerned with speed, the very first thing you should do is to profile your code, so that you can identify the bottlenecks. This will help you to determine *what* to optimize.

Comment: If you are truly concerned about efficiency, you could check the pypy project (yes, this is a Python interpreter) and more specifically the RPython language that was born out of it. The idea of RPython is to provide a core language for optimization of runtime operations, if your REPL interface can be mapped on RPython, you are done: JIT, runtime specializations, etc... you'll get a hell of a boost ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it very much depends on how your language works what you can do in an interpreter. Provided that this is a true interpreter and you don't have any precompile step you'd typically have two sorts of allocations - stack and heap allocations. If you support allocating things on the stack, you should implement this as a stack in your interpreter.

Use a `vector<char>` as a stack buffer. Keep track of each scope being entered, place a marker on the stack. When you encounter a stack allocated variable, grow the stack to accommodate the new local variable. Use placement `new` to initialize the object if that is required.

Add it to some sort of dictionary to match the variable name to the memory space so that your code knows where to find the name given the context. Like a symbol table really, only kept at run-time.

Once you encounter a scope end you will pop the stack of all the locally allocated symbols and call destructors if necessary. Also remove all the entries from the symbol table, since they are no longer in scope. This way you're avoiding the heap allocation entirely for objects that aren't used on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need inline assembler code to do that. You can use a `vector<char>` as buffer and construct your objects within that using [placement `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax). Note that with this technique you enter the realm of manual allocation management, which brings with it a host of problems, like dealing with fragmentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion, I will definately look into that

Comment: @user1166877: For handling the subtleties regarding memory allocations, take a look at the boost pool library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I've found is `std::map<std::string, Variant>`. The string stores the variable name, the `Variant` is a typedef for a `boost::variant<all-interpreter-types>`. That allows for code as easy as `globals["foo"]=1;` (sets interpreter variable `foo` to `int, 1`).

Sure, you could write your own code to do roughly the same, but then *you* have to worry about memory.